# GNURadio Embedded Python Block vs. Python Snippet. What is difference?

Tags: gnuradio

It seems as both blocks have same function. What is difference in concept, method, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

no, they don't have the same function.

One allows you to write a *block* in Python, i.e. to implement some functionality on a stream of data (or messages).

The other is just a *snippet of code* to be included in the final Python program that gets generated. That's something fundamentally different.

I'd recommend going through the chapters 1 to 5 (in that order!) of the GNU Radio academy on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org .